# How to compare 3 pairs of pandas dataframe columns which is of float type?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to compare 3 different pairs of one data-frame. In my data-frame's column some values are not float type i.e. "," is in between that values, so I want to remove "," from that values and then I want to convert that columns into float type. Last step is to compare three different pairs of data-frame columns.

**Dataframe:**

```
         aaa float_type1 float_type2 float_type3 float_type4 float_type5 float_type6
0  abc        1.12       1.120        1.20         1.2        1,67         167
1  xyz       1,2.5        2.35        1.25         125        12,5        12.5
2  pqr        3.56        3.58        35.6        3.78        3.90        5.56
3  pqr         5.5         5.8        5.05       5.005       5.500      5,5.78
4  pqr         6.6         6.9        6.06        6.06        6.60       6.600
```

**Program :**

```
def float_type_format(arg):

    arg = arg.replace(',', '')
    return arg

data = {'aaa' :{0:'abc',1:'xyz',2:'pqr',3:'pqr',4:'pqr'},
    'float_type1' :{0:'1.12',1:'1,2.5',2:'3.56',3:'5.5',4:'6.6'},
    'float_type2' :{0:'1.120',1:'2.35',2:'3.58',3:'5.8',4:'6.9'},
    'float_type3' :{0:'1.20',1:'1.25',2:'35.6',3:'5.05',4:'6.06'},
    'float_type4' :{0:'1.2',1:'125',2:'3.78',3:'5.005',4:'6.06'},
    'float_type5' :{0:'1,67',1:'12,5',2:'3.90',3:'5.500',4:'6.60'},
    'float_type6' :{0:'167',1:'12.5',2:'5.56',3:'5,5.78',4:'6.600'}}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)

#removing "," from float values    
df1['float_type1'] = df1['float_type1'].apply(float_type_format)
df1['float_type2'] = df1['float_type2'].apply(float_type_format)
df1['float_type3'] = df1['float_type3'].apply(float_type_format)
df1['float_type4'] = df1['float_type4'].apply(float_type_format)
df1['float_type5'] = df1['float_type5'].apply(float_type_format)
df1['float_type6'] = df1['float_type6'].apply(float_type_format)


#converting dtype into float 
df1.float_type1 = df1.float_type1.astype('float')
df1.float_type2 = df1.float_type2.astype('float')
df1.float_type3 = df1.float_type3.astype('float')
df1.float_type4 = df1.float_type4.astype('float')
df1.float_type5 = df1.float_type5.astype('float')
df1.float_type6 = df1.float_type6.astype('float')
```

For removing the "," from the column values I'm followed above logic.

**Question 1:**

Is their any fast performance and good way to remove "," from columns.

Now I want to compare float_type1 with float_type2, float_type3 with float_type4, float_type5 with float_type6 and if all 3 pairs are equal then only result column contain true and the expected output as follows:

```
aaa  float_type1  float_type2  float_type3  float_type4  float_type5  \
0  abc         1.12         1.12          1.2          1.2        167.0   

   float_type6 result  
0        167.0   True
```

**Question 2:**

I want a robust way of to perform this comparison.

Answer (score 3):

You can greatly simplify your code by using `replace` with `regex=True`. You can then convert to numeric with `pd.to_numeric` and then you can get the result column with some boolean logic.

```
df2 = df1.replace(',','',regex=True)
df2 = df2.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='ignore')

df2['result'] = ((df2['float_type1'] == df2['float_type2']) & 
                 (df2['float_type3'] == df2['float_type4']) & 
                 (df2['float_type5'] == df2['float_type6']))

   aaa  float_type1  float_type2  float_type3  float_type4  float_type5  \
0  abc         1.12         1.12         1.20        1.200        167.0   
1  xyz        12.50         2.35         1.25      125.000        125.0   
2  pqr         3.56         3.58        35.60        3.780          3.9   
3  pqr         5.50         5.80         5.05        5.005          5.5   
4  pqr         6.60         6.90         6.06        6.060          6.6   

   float_type6 result  
0       167.00   True  
1        12.50  False  
2         5.56  False  
3        55.78  False  
4         6.60  False
```

Comment: answer make sense. If **float_type1 is 0.0 or 0** and **float_type2 is nan or blank**, then I want to make it as **matched**?

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def float_type_format(arg):

    arg = arg.replace(',', '')
    return arg

data = {'aaa' :{0:'abc',1:'xyz',2:'pqr',3:'pqr',4:'pqr'},
    'float_type1' :{0:'1.12',1:'1,2.5',2:'3.56',3:'5.5',4:'6.6'},
    'float_type2' :{0:'1.120',1:'2.35',2:'3.58',3:'5.8',4:'6.9'},
    'float_type3' :{0:'1.20',1:'1.25',2:'35.6',3:'5.05',4:'6.06'},
    'float_type4' :{0:'1.2',1:'125',2:'3.78',3:'5.005',4:'6.06'},
    'float_type5' :{0:'1,67',1:'12,5',2:'3.90',3:'5.500',4:'6.60'},
    'float_type6' :{0:'167',1:'12.5',2:'5.56',3:'5,5.78',4:'6.600'}}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df1.head(6))

#removing "," from float values    
df1['float_type1'] = df1['float_type1'].apply(float_type_format)
df1['float_type2'] = df1['float_type2'].apply(float_type_format)
df1['float_type3'] = df1['float_type3'].apply(float_type_format)
df1['float_type4'] = df1['float_type4'].apply(float_type_format)
df1['float_type5'] = df1['float_type5'].apply(float_type_format)
df1['float_type6'] = df1['float_type6'].apply(float_type_format)



#converting dtype into float 
df1.float_type1 = df1.float_type1.astype('float')
df1.float_type2 = df1.float_type2.astype('float')
df1.float_type3 = df1.float_type3.astype('float')
df1.float_type4 = df1.float_type4.astype('float')
df1.float_type5 = df1.float_type5.astype('float')
df1.float_type6 = df1.float_type6.astype('float')



df1['test'] = (df1['float_type1']==df1['float_type2']) & (df1['float_type3']==df1['float_type4']) & (df1['float_type5']==df1['float_type6'])
print(df1.head(6))
```

It took me a while to realize you have all the df1['float_type1']
 in the replace part, thus making the whole dataframe the same. Lol

This is the way I come up, probably not the best way.

```
   aaa  float_type1  float_type2  float_type3  float_type4  float_type5  \
0  abc         1.12         1.12         1.20        1.200        167.0   
1  xyz        12.50         2.35         1.25      125.000        125.0   
2  pqr         3.56         3.58        35.60        3.780          3.9   
3  pqr         5.50         5.80         5.05        5.005          5.5   
4  pqr         6.60         6.90         6.06        6.060          6.6   

   float_type6   test  
0       167.00   True  
1        12.50  False  
2         5.56  False  
3        55.78  False  
4         6.60  False
```